# Insert Image and Change its Contrast and brightness levels based on the background Image

Tags: python, image, deep-learning, computer-vision, data-science

I am working on a project which involves me inserting an image into a background image but not just normally. I need the Image which needs to be inserted to match the contrast and brightness levels of the background image.
For example :
[Test Image 1 with Logo inserted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzu7l.png)

[Test Image 2 with Logo inserted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mygKN.png)

[Logo to insert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oqzo.png)

Any help on how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Compute the average intensity of the initial image, as well as its standard deviation, and repeat for the darker image. Now you will apply the following linear rule to the pixel values:

```
v' = σ'.(v - µ)/σ + µ' = σ'/σ.v + (µ' - σ'.µ/σ).
```

The exact correspondence between these coefficients and the contrast/brightness settings depend on how your software defines these.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on how do I calculate the average intensity and Standard deviation of image?

Answer (score 0):

First I would suggest you to find the dominant color of your ROI. By using
[Colorthief library](https://github.com/fengsp/color-thief-py). This will give the RGB color space of your bg. Then convert it to the LAB color space using skimage `skimage.color.rgb2lab(rgb[, illuminant, ...])`. I belive this will help you!